# Scala Compilation Error using Partition

Tags: scala

```
scala> val set = Set("apricot", "banana", "clementine", "durian", "fig", "guava", "jackfruit", "kiwi", "lime", "mango")
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String] = Set(banana, durian, fig, jackfruit, lime, mango, clementine, apricot, kiwi, guava)

scala> set.partition(_ length > 5)
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but integer literal found.
       set.partition(_ length > 5)
                                ^

scala> set.partition(_.length > 5)
res5: (scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String], scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.lang.String]) = (Set(banana, durian, jackfruit, clementine, apricot),Set(fig, lime, mango, kiwi, guava))
```

Can someone please explain why does it complain when I execute

```
set.partition(_ length > 5)
```

and not when I execute

```
set.partition(_.length > 5)
```

I have also tried the following with little success:

```
scala> set.partition((_ length) > 5)
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.length)
              set.partition((_ length) > 5)
                             ^
```

Comment: Wait, what happened to `"elderberry"`, `"huckleberry"`, and `"ilama"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you drop the dot, Scala assumes you have a one-parameter method.  In other words, when you say `_ length > 5` it thinks that `length` is a method requiring one argument, that `>` is that argument, and then it doesn't konw what to do with the 5.

Notice that this is similar to when you write `5 + 5`.  This statement is the same as writing `5.+(5)`, but you are dropping the dot and parentheses.  Scala notices the missing dot and assumes (correctly) that `+` is a method requiring a single argument.

If you write `"abc" length` by itself, then there is nothing for Scala to assume is the argument, so it then realizes that `length` doesn't require one.

So:

```
"abc".length        // fine
"abc" length        // fine
"abc".length > 4    // fine
("abc" length) > 4  // fine
"abc" length > 4    // error!
```

Thus, you need either a dot or parentheses to tell the compiler that `"abc"` and `length` go together and have no additional argument.

In terms of coding style, I suggest you always use the dot for zero-arg methods.  I find it more readable and it will help you to avoid compilation errors such as this one.

Comment: I have tried set.partition((_ length) > 5) but received the following 

scala> set.partition((_ length) > 5)
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.length)
              set.partition((_ length) > 5)

Comment: You'd have to do `partition(x => (x length) > 5)` because of the way Scala expands `_`

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```
set.partition(_ length > 5)
//            ^ object
//              ^ method
//                     ^ parameter
```

it treats `length` as a method that receives one parameter, `>`.

While when you write:

```
set.partition(_.length > 5)
//            ^------^ object
//                     ^ method
//                       ^ parameter
```

it treats `_.length` as the object, `>` is the parameter, and `5` is the argument.